# Need to insert Double Quotes for each fields when exporting to CSV file

Tags: excel, vba, csv

Need to insert Double Quotes for each fields when exporting to CSV file

```
Public Sub ExportWorksheetAndSaveAsCSV()

  Dim fn As String
  fn = "_" & Format(Now, "yyyymmddhhmmss")

  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Copy

  With ActiveWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    .SaveAs Filename:="C:\TMU-Export\TMU_Sales" & fn, FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    .Close savechanges:=False
  End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code uses the Stream object from the ADODB library to save the data in a UTF-8 CSV file, with each value enclosed within quotes.

```
Public Sub ExportWorksheetAndSaveAsCSV()

  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").UsedRange
  
  Dim txt As String
  Dim i As Long
  Dim j As Long
  txt = ""
  With rng
    For i = 1 To .Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To .Columns.Count
            If j = .Columns.Count Then
                txt = txt & """" & .Cells(i, j).Text & """" & vbCrLf
            Else
                txt = txt & """" & .Cells(i, j).Text & """" & ","
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
  End With
  
  Dim fn As String
  fn = "_" & Format(Now, "yyyymmddhhmmss")
  
  Dim stream As Object 'ADODB.stream
  Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.stream")
  
  With stream
    .Charset = "utf-8"
    .Type = 2 'adTypeText
    .Open
    .WriteText txt
    .SaveToFile "C:\TMU-Export\TMU_Sales" & fn & ".csv", 2 'adSaveCreateOverWrite
    .Close
  End With

End Sub
```

Source data:

[image]

UTF-8 CSV file:

```
"March 15, 2022","Doe, Jane","200","$1,300.25"
"May 24, 2022","Smith, John","300","$1,050.75"
```